# Firebase ID in Userdefaults

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am not able to read and write the firebase node ID in userdefaults

```
let userRef = recordRef.child("users")

let userRecord = userRef.childByAutoId()
let newUserId = userRecord.key
let newUserDict = ["id": newUserId , "username": "admin" , "password": password , "userType": "power" , "active": "yes"]
let newUser = Users(dictionary: newUserDict as [String: Any])
userRecord.setValue(newUser.toDictionary())

let userdefault = UserDefaults.standard //adding login details in defaults for auto login
userdefault.set(id!, forKey: "schoolId")
userdefault.set(code, forKey: "schoolCode")
userdefault.set("admin", forKey: "username")
userdefault.set(password, forKey: "password")
userdefault.set("power", forKey: "userType")
userdefault.set(newUserId!, forKey: "userId")
```

now when I am trying to read the schoolId or newUserID I am getting error of having NIL value

```
print(userDefaults.string(forKey: "userID")!)
print(userDefaults.string(forKey: "userType")!)
```

any idea how to read and write node id in user defaults?

Comment: An educated guess is that the `print` happens before the `userdefault.set`. Set breakpoints on both and run the code in the debugger to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same keys while adding/retrieving the object. You are using different key while saving i.e, `userId` and retrieving `userID` so because `userId` != `userID` you will get `nil` for this key.

A better solution would be to create an enum for `UserDefaults` keys as below,

```
enum UserDefaultKey: String {
    case schoolId
    case schoolCode
    case username
}
```

Extend `UserDefaults` to `set` and `get` the value using the enum item type,

```
extension UserDefaults {

    public func set<T>(_ value: T?, forKey: UserDefaultKey) {
        self.set(value, forKey: forKey.rawValue)
    }

    public func value<T>(ofType: T.Type, for key: UserDefaultKey) -> T? {
        return self.value(forKey: key.rawValue) as? T
    }
}
```

Then you can use these keys as below,

```
let userdefault = UserDefaults.standard
userdefault.set("YYYYY", forKey: .schoolId)
userdefault.set("Kam", forKey: .username)

print(userdefault.value(ofType: String.self, for: .schoolId)!)
print(userdefault.value(ofType: String.self, for: .username)!)
```